# play framework how to reuse and extend a form mapping

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a form mapping such as the following:

```
val myBaseMapping =  mapping(
  "email"                -> email,
  "password"             -> text.verifying("Please provide a password", !_.isEmpty)
)(BaseModel.apply)(BaseModel.unapply)
```

This represents `FormA`.  I have another form, `FormB`, that is identical but adds a couple more fields.  This is what its mapping would look like:

```
val myExtendedMapping =  mapping(
  "email"                -> email,
  "password"             -> text.verifying("Please provide a password", !_.isEmpty)
  "name"                 -> text,
  "website"              -> text
)(ChildModel.apply)(ChildModel.unapply)
```

`ChildModel` extends `BaseModel`: it adds 2 new fields, `name` and `website`.

I am trying to code `myExtendedMapping` in such a way that I don't have to duplicate the binding definitions for the shared fields (email and password).

I am not sure what the Scala syntax would be here. I do not know how to 'extend' a given mapping and add bindings to it. Also, I'd prefer not to add ad-hoc verification because of the difference in behavior.  Is this possible or do I just have to duplicate code?

Comment: What do each bind to?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but to use the mapping, I do: Form(myMapping) and then use that to bind from an HTTP request.

Comment: What I mean is, should `FormB` also bind to `MyModel`, or something else? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: Oh, I see: my current plan is to have another separate model class, say MyChildModel extend MyModel for use in the mappings for form B (adding in those extra attributes). So in other words I was looking for a way to have the form bindings parallel the model object structure. But I am definitely open to better ways to organize this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a simple composition. For example:

```
case class BaseModel(email: String, password: String)
case class ChildModel(name: String, website: String, base: BaseModel)

val commonMapping = mapping(
  "email" -> email,
  "passwod" -> texttext.verifying("Please provide a password", !_.isEmpty)
)(BaseModel.apply)(BaseModel.unapply)

val myExtendedForm = Form[ChildModel](mapping(
   "name" -> text,
   "website" -> text,
   "base" -> commonMapping
)
   ((name, website, base) => ChildModel(name, website, base))  //bind
   (child => Some(child.name, child.website, child.base))      //unbind
)
```